# Laravel query builder does not work as expected using orWhere conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to convert  the sql query to laravel

my sql query is working fine and show only active_state=1 record but laravel query qhows inactive rows also.what I did wrong

```sql
select a.id,a.assigned_user_name,a.meeting_start_date,a.call_start_date
from mgl_report_targets as a 
  left join dcalendardate b on b.datevalue=a.meeting_start_date 
  left join dcalendardate c on c.datevalue=a.call_start_date  
where (b.datevalue > '2020-07-31' and b.datevalue < '2020-09-01')
  or ( c.datevalue > '2020-07-31' and c.datevalue < '2020-09-01') 
  and a.active_status='1'
```

I have tried

```
$report_details=DB::table('mgl_report_targets');
$report_details=$report_details->leftjoin('dcalendardate as a','a.datevalue','=',DB::raw("mgl_report_targets.meeting_start_date::date")); 
$report_details=$report_details->leftjoin('dcalendardate as b','b.datevalue','=',DB::raw("mgl_report_targets.call_start_date::date"));
$report_details=$report_details->where('a.datevalue','>','2020-07-31');
$report_details=$report_details->where('a.datevalue','<','2020-09-01');
$report_details=$report_details->orWhere('b.datevalue','>','2020-07-31');
$report_details=$report_details->orWhere('b.datevalue','<','2020-09-01');
$report_details=$report_details->where('mgl_report_targets.active_status','=','1');
$report_details=$report_details->select('mgl_report_targets.id','mgl_report_targets.assigned_user_name','mgl_report_targets.meeting_start_date','mgl_report_targets.call_start_date')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the `()` wrapping the or conditions. By using `orWhere`, eloquent will only create a `OR` condition, without wrapping it into a parenthesis. You need to use a callback:

```php
$report_details=DB::table('mgl_report_targets')
   ->leftjoin('dcalendardate as a','a.datevalue','=',DB::raw("mgl_report_targets.meeting_start_date::date"))
   ->leftjoin('dcalendardate as b','b.datevalue','=',DB::raw("mgl_report_targets.call_start_date::date"))
   ->where(function ($query) { // <-- here you create the first '()`
      return $query->where('a.datevalue','>','2020-07-31')
        ->where('a.datevalue','<','2020-09-01');
   })
   ->orWhere(function ($query) { // <-- here you create the second '()`
      return $query->where('b.datevalue','>','2020-07-31')
        ->where('b.datevalue','<','2020-09-01');
   })
   ->where('mgl_report_targets.active_status','=','1')
   ->select('mgl_report_targets.id', 'mgl_report_targets.assigned_user_name', 'mgl_report_targets.meeting_start_date', 'mgl_report_targets.call_start_date')
```

This will create the following query:

```sql
select `mgl_report_targets`.`id`, `mgl_report_targets`.`assigned_user_name`, `mgl_report_targets`.`meeting_start_date`, `mgl_report_targets`.`call_start_date` 
from `mgl_report_targets` 
  left join `dcalendardate` as `a` on `a`.`datevalue` = mgl_report_targets.meeting_start_date::date 
  left join `dcalendardate` as `b` on `b`.`datevalue` = mgl_report_targets.call_start_date::date 
where (`a`.`datevalue` > ? and `a`.`datevalue` < ?) 
  or (`b`.`datevalue` > ? and `b`.`datevalue` < ?) 
  and `mgl_report_targets`.`active_status` = ?
```

It looks equivalent to your query to me

---

To better debug your query, you can use the `dd()` command to print the actual sql you are running:

```php
// Instead of
$report_details->get();

// use
$report_details->dd();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#debugging

Comment: other where condition followed by active_status is not working

Comment: I have splitted as $report_details=$report_details-> ....

Comment: Use the debug command to see the sql output and understand where is the difference with your original query

Comment: See my edit, I added the sql output. it looks equivalent to your original query to me